# Errors in JS number range when inputs over 999

Tags: javascript, html, numbers, range, primes

I was trying to write a script that puts out all primes in a certain range, this is my page with js code.

```html
<html>
<style>
.div1 {
    width: 69%;
}
</style>
<div class="div1">
<p id="otpt"></p>
</div>
<br>
<p id="hmpr"></p>
<script>
function isNInt(str) {
    return /^\+?(0|[1-9]\d*)$/.test(str);
}

var sat = prompt("Number to Start at: ")
while (isNInt(sat)==false){
  var sat = prompt("Not a valid Number: (Number to Start at)", sat)
}
var rti = prompt("Number to stop at: ")
while (isNInt(rti)==false){
  var rti = prompt("Not a valid Number: (Number to stop at)", rti)
}
//function to test if number is a prime number
function isPrime(num) {
  for(var i = 2; i < num; i++)
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
  return num !== 1;
}
var primecntr = 0
for (i=sat; i<rti; i++){
  if (isPrime(i)===true){
    document.getElementById('otpt').innerHTML = document.getElementById('otpt').innerHTML.concat(i, " ")
    var primecntr = primecntr+1
 }
}
document.getElementById('hmpr').innerHTML = primecntr + " Prime Numbers"
</script>
</html>
```

The code works for any number below 1000, but nothing above that. The error is recreated by putting in 200 and then 1000, it should print all prime numbers from 201 to 999 but the output is 0 Prime Numbers. If I can avoid it, I dont want to use jQuery for such a simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that your start and end variables were being stored as type `string`, not `number`. I've casted them, as well as made a few optimizations:

- The `isPrime()` function now only checks up to the square root (as otherwise your just getting duplicate factors) - this makes a big difference as the values increase.
- I've stored your output in a string and then written it at the end to avoid writing content to the DOM repeatedly.

```html
<html>
<style>
.div1 {
    width: 69%;
}
</style>
<div class="div1">
<p id="otpt"></p>
</div>
<br>
<p id="hmpr"></p>
<script>
function isNInt(str) {
    return /^\+?(0|[1-9]\d*)$/.test(str);
}

var sat = prompt("Number to Start at: ")
while (!isNInt(sat)){
  var sat = prompt("Not a valid Number: (Number to Start at)", sat)
}
var rti = prompt("Number to stop at: ")
while (!isNInt(rti)){
  var rti = prompt("Not a valid Number: (Number to stop at)", rti)
}
//function to test if number is a prime number
function isPrime(num) {
  for(var i = 2; i < Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num)) + 1; i++)
    if(num % i === 0) return false;
  return num !== 1;
}
sat = Number(sat);
rti = Number(rti);
var primecntr = 0;
var primeString = "";
for (i=sat; i<rti; i++) {
  if (isPrime(i)) {
    primeString = primeString.concat(i, " ");
    primecntr++;
  }
}
document.getElementById('otpt').textContent = primeString;
document.getElementById('hmpr').textContent = primecntr + " Prime Numbers";
</script>
</html>
```

This can be tested with the snippet, pick any end number > 999.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure starting value is 200 and stopping value is 100.

You need to check starting value is less than stopping value.

```
if(sat > rti){
   /* change rti value to maximum possible value with number of 
      digits in sat value.
   */
   var power = rti.toString().length-1;
   rti = Math.pow(10, power) - 1;
}
```

Comment: I think he meant 1000, if you use that the function still doesn't work

Comment: Though you're not wrong, the inputs should be tested!